# Error facing while parsing xml java

Tags: xml-parsing, jaxb, saxparser

i am trying to parse an Xml file in which one pf the tag element is as below

```
126.5�105�15-4�45�-16MnCr5-1
```

when i tried parse using jaxb and read the xml the content gets chaged to as below

```
126.5 �— 105 �— 15-4�—45°-16MnCr5-1
```

i don't know why i checked with the unicode format too by default it is taking the cp1252 format not the UTF-8 FORMAT even though i specified in the xml kinldy help here is the method which reads the xml passed are attributes xml file and jaxbclass mapping

```
protected T readXml(File xmlFile, Class<?> clazz) throws JAXBException, IOException, XMLStreamException {
  JAXBContext jaxbContext = null;
  Unmarshaller unmarshaller = null;
  jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
  unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
  XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
  XMLStreamReader streamReader = null;
  streamReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(xmlFile));
  return (T) unmarshaller.unmarshal(streamReader);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try passing encoding while reading contents from file.

```
streamReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(xmlFile),"UTF-8");
```

that should fix it.